# Borei P'ri or Borei F'ri hagefen?

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, nuschaot, grapes-wine, kiddush

Have heard a few older mizrahi recordings for qiddush and am noticing that some of them use borei f'ri hagefen. When i looked up Qiddush in my Egyptian siddur (Farhi Siddur) i noticed the Pei had no dagesh. It makes sense to me grammatically that it would be f'ri as the Borei ends with an aleph, and usually that removes the dagesh from the word that follows. Anyone have any sources? Or have access to ancient siddurim with nekkudoth to see if they put the dagesh in the pei or not?

Update: I've now collected an older Livorno siddur that also has f'ri, as well as Yemenite siddurim that all have f'ri. So this seems to be consistent amongst older non Ashkenazi communities.

Comment: It would make sense to have the Dagesh, because Borei is on a pause. It's not "borei-fri, hagafen". It's "borei, peri-hagafen". (ROY has a teshuva about this IINM.)

Comment: teimonim say faree

Comment: @DoubleAA If _bore_ is a noun, "the creator of", then it's got _s'michus_ and there should be a _fe_.  If it's a verb, "Who creates", then not. Afaict.

Comment: @msh210 i agree with your thought.

Comment: @DoubleAA How would one know it's on a pause without te'amim?

Comment: @Aaron Taamim are just reflecting natural grammar and syntax.

Comment: @DoubleAA Right, but if it's natural grammar and syntax, how can you have mizrahi communities (such as yemenites or Egyptians or Iraqis) going "there is a natural lack of pause here." And Ashkenazim going "there is a natural pause here." It doesn't make sense to me?

Comment: @Aaron They each think that theirs is the natural way of phrasing it. What doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because in English there might be a debate regarding the Oxford comma, but other than that most English speakers know where a natural pause should or aught be. Whereas with this, it seems like if we didn't have the Mosoretic markings, everyone might place the Etnachtas/Atnachs in different places.

Comment: @msh210 -- I don't think that grammatical distinction exists in Biblical Hebrew. More like the language lacks a real present tense; instead: you are what you are doing.

There is also another possible difference: Ashkenazim and Teimanim pray in Biblical Hebrew, which is why we use the pausal form, "hagafen". Whereas Sepharadim pray in Mishnaic Hebrew, which is why they say "hagefen". (Also, why Ashk has "qadsheinu bemitzvosekha" and Seph has "... bemitzvosakh".) They may or may not have different grammatical rules here too, I don't know.

Comment: @MichaBerger So then if both Ashkenazim and Yemenites use Biblical Hebrew, why do Ashkenazim say p'ri and Yemenits say f'ri?

Comment: @Aaron Just because we don't have masoretic markings doesn't mean people put it wherever. That would, be inane: frankly?. Any natural speaker of a language knows where pauses go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is halakhic justification for the custom of vocalizing a stress-less *feri* as a more grammatically correct way of saying the blessing. In his responsa *Or Letzion*, (vol. 2, chapter 46, halakha 34), the Sephardic rabbi, Ben Tzion Abba Shaul (1924-1998), wrote:

> יותר מדוקדק לומר בורא פרי הגפן וכן בורא פרי העץ ובורא פרי האדמה
> כשהאות פ' של המילה פרי רפויה
>
> שכן אותיות בג״ד כפ״ת אחר אותיות אהו״י רפויות הן. ואין לומר שיש הפסק בורא לפרי, שהרי המילה בורא אין לה משמעות בפני עצמה, ועל כרחך שהמילה פרי נמשכת אחר המילה בורא, ואם היה זה פסוק בתורה, הטעמים היו מאריך טרחא סוף פסוק
>
> It is more accurate to say *borei **f**eri hagefen* and also *borei **f**eri ha-etz* and *borei **f**eri ha-adamah* with the letter *peh* of the word as a stress-less ***f**eri*.
>
> This is because, grammatically, the letters *bet, gimmel, dalet, kaf, peh,* and *tav*, when following the
> letters *alef heh vav* and *yud* become stress-less. And it is not right
> to say that there is a pause between *borei* and *peri*, since
> the word *borei* [the Creator of] doesn't have a meaning by itself,
> as it is necessary for the word *feri* [fruit] to continue after the
> word *borei* to make sense. And if it was a verse in the Torah, the cantillation
> would be a *ma'arikh tarḥa sof pasuq*.

It should be stated that the custom for many Sepharadim is to still say *peri* with a stressed *peh*. R. Ovadia (*Yabia Omer*, O.Ḥ. 9:22) specifically countered the position of *Or Letzion*, stating that, grammatically, there should be a stressed *peh* because there actually *is* a brief pause between the two words in the blessing. The grammatical rule applies to words joined by context. Among other proofs that he uses from Tanakh, he cites a very similar parallel in the vocalization of Gen. 1:11, where a *peh* follows a *heh* (which should normally make it stress-less):

> עֹשֶׂ**ה** **פְּ**רִי לְמִינוֹ
>
> 'ose**h** **p**eri le-mino

Moreover, R. Ovadia goes on to say that the grammatical rule above is not so firm:

> ובכלל נראה שהכלל של אהו"י הסמוכות לבג"ד כפ"ת שעושות אותן רפויות, אינו
> כלל החלטי, ופעמים רבות שדוחים כלל זה מפני סיבות אחרות מוצדקות
>
> In any case, it doesn't seem like the rule of the letters *alef heh vav* and *yud* in connection with the *bet gimmel dalet kaf peh* and *tav* to make the latter stress-less --is actually a decisive rule, as there are plenty of times when that rule is rejected for other justifiable reasons.

R. Ovadia then proceeds to list various other occurrences when the rule is not followed (e.g., *m**i** **kh**amokhah ba-'elim Hashem, m**i** **k**amokha ne'edar ba-qodesh*) to dismantle the stringency of the grammatical rule.

Comment: Rav Ovadia is mistaken, if accurately represented. The dagesh in the phrase    עֹשֶׂה פְּרִי  is not due to a slight pause, but rather a dagesh chazak due to the words being connected (called אתי מרחיק)

Comment: Thank you for the sources!

Comment: There are plenty of verses with a participle that "doesn't have a meaning by itself" coming on a mafsiq. Even a few with בורא: Isaiah 40:28 and 57:19.

Comment: @DoubleAA ועץ עושה "פרי" אשר זרעו בו למינהו, אות פ' דגושה. וכתב במנחת שי שם שהטעם שהם בדגש, הראשון מדין מפסיק ואתי מרחיק, והשני מדין דחיק שהוא במקף

Comment: @Aryeh I made an edit to your answer that I think is closer to what you were trying to say/closer to the Hebrew. Let me know if you disagree

Comment: "kamocha" is one of exactly 10 known exceptions which are all listed out. Hardly evidence that the rule shouldn't apply here. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47618/759

Comment: @Aryeh I'm guessing by מפסיק there Minchat Shai is referring to the consonant ending in previous phrase עץ פרי which is the first instance of פ with a dagesh, though even that is weird. If someone has access to Betser's edition of Minchat Shai please enlighten us, as this is plausibly a typo. Either way what he's saying in this answer is still mistaken.

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe he was mistaken, although that’s a pretty easy (and might I add, dismissive) thing to type

Comment: As the Noda Bihuda wrote "Why are you asking me grammar questions? I'm a rabbi! Go ask a grammarian"

Comment: See for example https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91369/759 which calls these "conjunctive dagesh" and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11299/759 which discusses 'squeezing' the two words together. There's just no way these examples from Tanakh are relevant to the bracha under discussion.