# Secondary stress after the main stress in פדנה

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashat-toldot

Rashi notes [multiple times](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22155/15256) that the -ל prefix can be substituted by a ה- suffix like in [Bereishit 28:2](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0128.htm#2):

> ק֥וּם לֵךְ֙ **פַּדֶּ֣נָֽה** אֲרָ֔ם בֵּ֥יתָה בְתוּאֵ֖ל אֲבִ֣י אִמֶּ֑ךָ וְקַח־לְךָ֤ מִשָּׁם֙ אִשָּׁ֔ה מִבְּנ֥וֹת לָבָ֖ן אֲחִ֥י אִמֶּֽךָ׃
>
> Arise, go **to Paddan**-aram, to the house of Bethuel thy mother's father; and take thee a wife from thence of the daughters of Laban thy mother's brother.

In almost [all](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.14) [cases](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.10) [I](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.28.12) [know](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.67), this last syllable won't be accented, however, in פדנה there's a secondary stress on the last syllable.* Does it happen due to a [retracted accent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11295/15256) *(nasog achor)?* Doesn't it matter that there's a semi-vowel in addition? Are you aware of other examples where the syllable pushing back the accent contains a *chataf* as well?

<sup>* In longer words it's normal to have a secondary stress *before* the primary accent. I assume usually they're before the main one, because the majority of Hebrew words have an ultimate stress.</sup>

Comment: Maybe compensating for the missing dagesh? Cf. Gen 46:1.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11295/759 (off the top of my head, also numbers 17:23 and isaiah 40:8)

Comment: @DoubleAA Those are clearly _nasog achor_ cases. Does it also work here, as the _chataf patach_ doesn't constitute a syllable on its own?

Comment: The Leningrad codex has this kind of meseg in many places where there's a word with a sheva na + one syllable.  ודרשת והגידו לך at the beginning of parshas Shoftim and many others.

Comment: Sorry, not והגידו, it's יגידו in 17:10 and 17:11.

Comment: Also הסכלת עשו in shishi of vayeitzei

Comment: @Heshy Then it's not a _nasog achor,_ because no stress is retracted, right?

Comment: @Kazi I agree.  I don't have an explanation, I've just observed that the Leningrad codex has these mesagim a lot before a sheva-na-plus-one-syllable word, sometimes when the previous word is nasog achor but sometimes when it's just plain mile'eil.  I don't think פדנה is a nasog achor either (think מצרימה).

Comment: Also הנה חלמתי חלום עוד beginning of Vayeishev

Comment: @Heshy I've looked up the case in R' Breuer's book (see answer), but he doesn't list your [second](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/1/31/28) example, because the syllable with a _gayah_ follows a closed syllable. Your [first](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/5/17/10) one seems to fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mordechai Breuer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordechai_Breuer) called this phenomenon the *gayah* of a long vowel in an open syllable (§46 – געיית התנועה הגדולה בהברה פתוחה). In such cases there is an unaccented open syllable with a long vowel followed by a second accented syllable. On pp. 207–208 in *Taamei haMiqra* he brings several examples:

- In the first group this syllable is followed by a *sheva* or a *chataf:*
  ק֥וּם לֵךְ֙ פַּדֶּ֣נָֽה אֲרָ֔ם ([Bereishit 28:2](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0128.htm#2))
  וַיֵּֽנִקֵ֤הֽוּ דְבַשׁ֙ מִסֶּ֔לַע ([Devarim 32:13](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0532.htm#13))
  שִׂים־לְפָנֶ֣יךָֽ אֱכֹ֔ל ([Samuel I 9:24](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c08a09.htm#24))*
- In the second group the following word has an initial stress and a *pashta:*
  וְעָ֤שָֽׂה פֶ֨סַח֙ לַֽיהוָ֔ה ([Bemidbar 9:14](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0409.htm#14))
  וְאַתָּ֞ה עָשִׂ֤יתָֽה חֶ֨סֶד֙ ([Samuel I 15:6](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c08a15.htm#6))
  וְאֶת־דְּמֵ֨י בָנָ֜יו רָאִ֤יתִֽי אֶ֨מֶשׁ֙ ([Kings II 9:26](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c09b09.htm#26))*
- In the third group there are the exceptions:
  אֲ֠שֶׁר לֹֽא־הָיָ֨ה כָמ֥וֹךָֽ אִ֛ישׁ ([Kings I 3:13](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c09a03.htm#13))*
  וְנֶ֨פֶשׁ עֲבָדֶ֥יךָֽ אֵ֛לֶּה ([Kings II 1:13](https://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c09b01.htm#13))

<sup>* Here Mechon Mamre omits the *gayah,* but there is one in the Aleppo Codex.</sup>